# How to identify existing partition structure on unbootable & broken linux system

Tags: mount, boot, chroot, partition-table

I am running Arch linux.

The kernel was broken and would not boot, as described here.
[Linux won't boot, arch kernel is broken, how to fix?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/630207/linux-wont-boot-arch-kernel-is-broken-how-to-fix)

Luckily I had an identically built unbroken system, from which I was able to determine the correct partition mount points, before chrooting into the system and implementing the fix.

My question is, if I had not had an identical system to get the mount points information from, how, booting off a live linux on a USB stick, would I have determined the correct mount points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't tell what partitions are supposed to be mounted on `/` or `/home` from a Live system without actually mounting them. It's possible to make some educated guesses from `lsblk` output -- size, position and filesystem type (`lsblk -f` prints filesystem type) can tell you a lot but other than that, you actually need to mount each partition and check their content (and once you find `/` you can use `/etc/fstab` for the others).

Few things that might help:

- With "advanced" setups like LVM you can check names of the logical volumes, they should correspond with the LV intended usage (but naming `/` `root` and `/home` `home` etc. is just a custom, not enforced).
- GPT has [special GUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs) for partition "types", both `/home` and `/` have GUID that can be used, but these can be omitted and for example Fedora installer doesn't set these during installation.
- Boot/kernel parameters from the original system can tell you what partition is `/` (if you can manage to get GRUB running).

Comment: If gpt you also have a backup partition table. You can export a list of partitions. Backup partition table structure to text file & save to external device.
sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda > PTsda.txt  I include bootinfoscript report (or Boot-Repair) as part of my normal backup, just to document system. Updated fork  as original bootinfoscript does not seem to be maintained
https://github.com/arvidjaar/bootinfoscript  Yann (Boot-Repair) updated script to include NMVe drives correctly, but now had modified it even more and it is embedded into Boot-Repair. Boot-Repair requires a gui.